# Hide table header <th> existence fully and on hover display it

Tags: html, css

i want to hide `<th>` such a way that happens when we give `display:none` but if i use this property i can't display it on mouse hover.i placed an up arrow inside the th to point something on hovering the table;
** When my table is not in hovered state those th remain hidden but there remain  blank space which i do not want.**
I have tried using like this `margin-top:-555px;` and on hover `margin-top:0`  but does not work.
[image: current output]

i do not want the red mark area but hover state on given link is ok for me.
please help.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3L70uw6/)

```
<div class="existing_items">
<table cellspacing="0">
    <th class="pointer"colspan="2"><span>^</span></th>
    <tr><th class="" colspan="2">Title</th></tr>
    <tr><td class="leftname">name</td><td>name</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="leftname">type</td><td>type</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

```css
.existing_items{
    background-color:green;
}
.existing_items table td{
text-align:center;
border-top:1px solid #eaeaea;
}
table:hover th.pointer{
visibility:visible;
} 

table th.pointer{
color:red;
visibility:hidden;
font-size:20px;
}
.leftname{
border-right:1px solid #eaeaea;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to hide the hole table or just the rows?

Comment: just the row of table the first <th> of the table

Comment: I would suggest looking at how navigation bars do it

Comment: If you hide th,which time you want to show it?Which event you want to trigger?

Comment: on hovering the table i want to show it its content and i just want to hide <th><span>^</span></th> and show on hover

Comment: Why are you using this empty `<th>` element? What purpose is it serving?

Comment: You can try my answer,but i don't think it's the best one;It should be better,but i don't know how to do it;

Comment: @i alarmed alien to contain my ^ and show bold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add `position:inherit;` in your `table:hover th.pointer` and it works;
You can try here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gkiwi/t7eecbzp/

Or

```css
.existing_items{
    background-color:green;
}
.existing_items table td{
    text-align:center;
    border-top:1px solid #eaeaea;
}
table:hover th.pointer{
    visibility:visible;
    top:-10px;
    left:20px;
    position:inherit;
} 

table th.pointer{
    color:red;
    visibility:hidden;
    font-size:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}
.leftname{
    border-right:1px solid #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<div class="existing_items">
<table cellspacing="0">
    <th class="pointer"colspan="2"><span>^</span></th>
    <tr><th class="" colspan="2">Title</th></tr>
    <tr><td class="leftname">name</td><td>name</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="leftname">type</td><td>type</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to **not** use an extra (useless) `<th>` for this purpose. You could instead use a pseudo-element on your title `<th>`, as they seems highly related. See my example below:

```css
.existing_items{
    background-color:green;
}
.existing_items table td{
    text-align:center;
    border-top:1px solid #eaeaea;
}
table th.with-arrow {
    position: relative;
}
table:hover th.with-arrow:after{
    content: "^";
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 0;
    color: red;
    font-size:20px;
} 
.leftname{
    border-right:1px solid #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<div class="existing_items">
    <table cellspacing="0">
        <tr><th class="with-arrow" colspan="2">Title</th></tr>
        <tr><td class="leftname">name</td><td>name</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="leftname">type</td><td>type</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```